# How to run Python code using Codon in Ubuntu

Tags: python

I have a Python code, and I wanna use [Codon](https://github.com/exaloop/codon) to run it. To do this, I first need to install it. I copy and paste the code
`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://exaloop.io/install.sh)"`
in terminal. Every time that I run this code, it install codon again and I face the following results.

```
PATH export command:
  export PATH=/home/aaron/.codon/bin:$PATH
Could not find bash configuration file to update PATH
Codon successfully installed at: /home/aaron/.codon
Open a new terminal session or update your PATH to use codon
```

My Python file called code.py is in Downloads folder. Now, to run the code, I open the terminal in Downloads folder, I use the command `codon run code.py`. However, when I do this, I face the following error. I would be thankful if you could let me know how to fix it.

```
Command 'codon' not found, did you mean:
  command 'codonw' from deb codonw (1.4.4-6)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

I should add that I just installed Ubuntu and I am not familiar with it. I am a Windows user!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your `$HOME/.bashrc` file.

```
export PATH=/home/aaron/.codon/bin:$PATH
```

Then run `source .bashrc` (once and for all).

---

Afterwards, you should be able to run `codon run code.py`

Comment: Thank you so much. In my code, I imported some libraries like numpy, scipy, matplotlib, pandas, etc. When I want to run it, I face some errors like ```code.py:1:8-13: error: no module named 'numpy'```. 
is it possible to run it with codon using all libraries in anaconda?

Comment: When I use the code ```python code.py``` in terminal, it runs the code. But when I use codon, I face that error/

Comment: I don't know how to get numpy to work with codon (I am not familiar with Codon at all). Please open an issue at GitHub and ask a question there.

Comment: Also see - https://github.com/exaloop/codon/issues/224#issuecomment-1466119313 which says "Codon does not support numpy yet".

Comment: I really appreciate your help.